# Android DataBinding showing merged string with null check not working

Tags: android, android-layout, android-databinding

I need to have show merged string through data binding. I can able to show it by below code easily.

```
android:text='@{sentRequestItems.receiver.firstName + " " + sentRequestItems.receiver.lastName}'
```

But in some case their is possibility that last name getting null form API response so in that case i can not able to show last name with null check.

I am trying with below code.

```
android:text='@{sentRequestItems.receiver.firstName != null ? sentRequestItems.receiver.firstName : "" + " " + sentRequestItems.receiver.lastName != null ? sentRequestItems.receiver.lastName : ""}'
```

Here with this it is not showing last name when it is not null in API response.

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
      android:id="@+id/txvContactName"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
      android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_8sdp"
      android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_4sdp"
      android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/ivCancelRequest"
      android:fontFamily="@font/lato_bold"
      android:text='@{sentRequestItems.receiver.firstName != null ? sentRequestItems.receiver.firstName : "" + " " + sentRequestItems.receiver.lastName != null ? sentRequestItems.receiver.lastName : ""}'
      android:textColor="@color/black"
      android:textSize="@dimen/_15ssp"
      tools:text="John Donny">
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: use this in your model class **var lastName : String?**

Comment: @PrafulPatel You mean need to declare that string "" from model class itself ? I am having auto generated model classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's not a best idea to perform coding in xml, readability suffers.
I suggest you to create static method, something like

```
class Utils {
  static String formatName(RequestItem sentRequestItems) {
     return (sentRequestItems.receiver.firstName != null ? 
             sentRequestItems.receiver.firstName : "") + " " + 
             (sentRequestItems.receiver.lastName != null ? sentRequestItems.receiver.lastName : "")
  }
}
```

It's simplier to debug.
Also, don't forget brackets. You code doesn't work, because if first comparison `sentRequestItems.receiver.firstName != null` succeeds, all expression just returns `sentRequestItems.receiver.firstName`.

then in import it in your xml and use, like

```
android:text="@{Utils.formatName(sentRequestItems)}"
```

Comment: But actually i am having issue with that part only the code you have shown as return statement is not showing last name when it is actually having a value and at that moment it is not null. So i want to have show the last name when it is not null.

Comment: This solution has some how helped me but i have created own different function in utils and able to show the first name  & last name as intended now. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You can use BindingAdapter.
In Kotlin.
**Step 1**
Create a class BindingAdapters where you will have all your binding adapters method.

**Step 2: Create a function like below**

> @BindingAdapter("app:contact_name")
>       @JvmStatic
>       fun setContactName(tvContactName: TextView, sentRequest: SentRequestItems?) {
>      if(sentRequest.receiver!=null){

if(sentRequest.receiver.lastName.isNullOrEmpty()){

tvContactName.text=sentRequest.receiver.firstName

}else{

tvContactName.text="$sentRequest.receiver.firstName 
$sentRequest.receiver.firstName"

}

```
}   

}
```

**Step 3: Add the attribute in your text view**

app:contact_name="@{sentRequestItems}"